# SpriteKit SKNode User Data returning nil

Tags: ios, swift3, sprite-kit, nsmutabledictionary, skspritenode

I am using the userData of an SKSpriteNode to save custom data into it.
I have initialized the userData with value through this line of code:

```
oscIcon.userData = NSMutableDictionary()
oscIcon.userData?.setValue("0.01",forKey: "rValue")
print("init value = \(oscIcon.userData!["rValue"])")
```

I then use this userData value in another function :

```
print("using value = \(oscIcon.userData!["rValue"])")
let tempValHold = oscIcon.userData!["rValue"] as! CGFloat
selectedNode.zRotation = tempValHold + (translation.y * 0.01)
```

However, I am getting a crash with error Fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Printing the value in the first chunk of code returns

```
init value = Optional(0.01)
```

while printing the value from the second chunk returns this

```
using value = nil
```

I am not able to figure out why my saved userData just disappears.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where do you use first chunk of code, and where the second chunk comes from? Personally, I would say, that you are operating on different node which doesn't have `userData` initialized at all.